# Granting events view permission in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rbac, rancher

We have local Kubernetes clusters that are managed by Rancher and we use Terraform to have our configuration in code. However, I cannot seem to be able to grant my group `devops` permission to view events in the clusters.

These are the role and role binding:

```
resource "rancher2_role_template" "events-view" {
  name = "Cluster Events View"
  description = "Terraform role template to see cluster events"
  rules {
    api_groups     = ["*"]
    resources      = ["events"]
    verbs          = ["get", "watch"]
  }
}

resource "rancher2_cluster_role_template_binding" "events-view" {
  name = "events-view"
  cluster_id = rancher2_cluster.rancher_cluster.id
  role_template_id = rancher2_role_template.events-view.id
  group_principal_id = lookup(var.projects["devops"] , "ldap_cn")
  depends_on = [
    rancher2_role_template.events-view
  ]
}
```

This is the `devops` definition:

```
projects = {
    devops = {
        ldap_cn = "activedirectory_group://CN=devops,OU=Distribution Groups,OU=My,DC=Company",
        name = "devops",
        # ...more attributes
    },
    # ...more projects
}
```

When I run `terraform apply` I see that the role and the role binding are created:

```
rancher2_role_template.events-view: Creating...
rancher2_role_template.events-view: Creation complete after 0s [id=rt-h7xt4]
rancher2_cluster_role_template_binding.events-view: Creating...
rancher2_cluster_role_template_binding.events-view: Creation complete after 2s [id=c-6bdtb:events-view]
```

`kubectl` shows the cluster role and role binding (showing for the default namespace, but duplicated across all namespaces as well):

```
$ kubectl describe clusterrole rt-h7xt4
Name:         rt-h7xt4
Labels:       cattle.io/creator=norman
Annotations:  authz.cluster.cattle.io/clusterrole-owner: rt-h7xt4
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  events.*   []                 []              [get watch]

$ kubectl describe clusterrolebinding clusterrolebinding-hkc9b
Name:         clusterrolebinding-hkc9b
Labels:       authz.cluster.cattle.io/rtb-owner=6f990492-8f60-4950-bb8e-cfa4a9760c01
              cattle.io/creator=norman
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  rt-h7xt4
Subjects:
  Kind   Name                                                                                         Namespace
  ----   ----                                                                                         ---------
  Group  activedirectory_group://CN=devops,OU=Distribution Groups,OU=My,DC=Company
```

My user is a member of the `devops` AD group, and in the `terraform apply` log I can see that the role and binding templates are created, yet when I log into Rancher and click on `Launch kubectl` I cannot see the events of any namespace:

```
> kubectl get events 
Error from server (Forbidden): events is forbidden: User "u-w8rp43jtbn" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
> kubectl get events -n devops
Error from server (Forbidden): events is forbidden: User "u-w8rp44jtbn" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "devops"
```

I've tried putting and empty string in `api_groups` and also the Kubernetes and Rancher API groups, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Edit the question to add relevant role and rolebinding of the user

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I don't have a role for my user - the relevant role and role binding are those of the devops group. My intention is to have each member of the devops group to inherit the group's roles.

Comment: Okay..can you share the role and rolebinding of the group to which the user belongs?

Comment: I don't think I understand you... The role and role binding I put here are those of devops. The user I log in to Rancher is a member of devops - why are the role and role binding of devops not relevant?

Comment: Your terraform is creating 2 resources, `rancher2_role_template` and `rancher2_cluster_role_template_binding`, please provide the output of the generated template for the `clusterrole`. Is hard to say anything only seeing your terraform config without see how the `clusterrole` was created in k8s.

Comment: @KoopaKiller thanks, I added a log snippet of terramform that shows the creation of the template and a description of the role and role binding in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I made a cluster role template instead of a project role template.
In the `rancher2_role_template` resource I added `context = "project"` and changed the `rancher2_cluster_role_template_binding` to a `rancher2_project_role_template_binding`.